# Angular ApexChart does not plot anything if height= "100%"

Tags: angular, apexcharts

I am experiencing this problem with angular. I've made minimal changes to the demo code, and it works if I set width=100%

but as soon as set height=100% it displays complete blank except for the 3 lines in the upper right and corner that provide the ability to export image.

I see information about this issue with react, but I can't figure out how their solution would apply in angular.

app.component.html looks like:

```
<style>
.chartDiv {
  margin: 2;
  width: 95%;
  height: 95%;
  /* border: 1px solid blue; */
}   
</style>


<div class="chartDiv">
  <apx-chart
  [series]="chartOptions.series"
  [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
  [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
>
</apx-chart>

</div>
```

and app.component.ts looks like:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

import {
  ChartComponent,
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexTitleSubtitle
} from "ng-apexcharts";

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
};

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  public chartOptions: ChartOptions;
  title!: 'Charting';
  
  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: "My-series",
          data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148]
        }
      ],
      chart: {
        width: "100%",
        height: "100%",
        type: "bar"
      },
      title: {
        text: "My First Angular Chart"
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: ["Jan", "Feb",  "Mar",  "Apr",  "May",  "Jun",  "Jul",  "Aug", "Sep"]
      }
    };
  }
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things and finally realized width of 100% is fine be height of 100% causes the problem.  If I don't set height it creates a mess if the aspect ratio is not 10:16.

I've seen solutions for react or vue, but not angular, and I can't understand those other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate CSS to fix

```
.chartDiv apx-chart {
    flex: 1;
}
```

Here is a working example to get you started.

1. You can just set the container to `display: flex` for the class `chartDiv` this will ensure the child element stretches the full height of the parent!
2. Secondly, you can remove the style tag on the HTML, angular expects the styles to be set in the styles array, since we have `View Encapsulation` to ensure that component CSS does not mess up other components CSS (the CSS gets scoped to that particular component!
3. You can customize the width and height based on this. Here is a sample CSS for you to reference how to size the chart

CSS

```
  :host {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
  }
  .chartDiv{ 
    display: flex;
    width:100% !important;
    height:100% !important;
  }
  .chartDiv apx-chart {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
  }
```

4. We can use `:host` to style the root tag of the element, prefer to use `display: block` and set the width and height of the component, else the root tag will not have a height and this will lead to more issues.
5. If you want to set the height of the chart, do ensure that the height is set on the parent of the chart, then set height and width to `100%` to the chart, this will help!

Hope this helps solve your issue!

```
import 'zone.js';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import {
  ChartComponent,
  ApexAxisChartSeries,
  ApexChart,
  ApexXAxis,
  ApexTitleSubtitle,
  NgApexchartsModule,
} from 'ng-apexcharts';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

export type ChartOptions = {
  series: ApexAxisChartSeries;
  chart: ApexChart;
  xaxis: ApexXAxis;
  title: ApexTitleSubtitle;
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="chartDiv">
      <apx-chart
        [series]="chartOptions.series"
        [chart]="chartOptions.chart"
        [xaxis]="chartOptions.xaxis"
      ></apx-chart>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
      :host {
        display:block;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }
      .chartDiv{ 
        display: flex;
        width:100% !important;
        height:100% !important;
      }
      .chartDiv apx-chart {
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
      }
    `,
  ],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule, NgApexchartsModule],
})
export class AppComponent {
  public chartOptions: ChartOptions;
  title!: 'Charting';

  constructor() {
    this.chartOptions = {
      series: [
        {
          name: 'My-series',
          data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148],
        },
      ],
      chart: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
        type: 'bar',
      },
      title: {
        text: 'My First Angular Chart',
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: [
          'Jan',
          'Feb',
          'Mar',
          'Apr',
          'May',
          'Jun',
          'Jul',
          'Aug',
          'Sep',
        ],
      },
    };
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmnzm7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Comment: thank you. 

I've made the changes to my code but I get a completely white screen. As soon as I remove the         height: '100%', from the chartOptions definition I get a graph but it spills out of the area.

I see only a white screen when I click on your stackblitz link, but, I tried adding a simple <p>Hello</p> into the html and never saw it appear on the screen. I'm not familar with stackblitz.  Is there something I need to do to start it running?

Comment: @RodneyEast Its strange, I opened the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmnzm7) just now and it was rendering a chart, could you open in a new browser, or on incognito?

Comment: I just opened it with a different browser and it renders, but the height is maybe 150 pixels but full width, which is similar what I was able to get wiith my code base after I realized that I was still pointing to chartDiv instead of apex-chart

so yes I'm now seeing a plot but it is not fill the enclosing div

Comment: @RodneyEast please replicate in the stackblitz and share back for checking the issue

Comment: The dimension of the graph is 650X170 in Stackblitz, but the window is almost square 650X650.

What I am wanting is something that fills a given size enclosing div.  In this case that should be the entire page.  In my real case I expect a header at the top and eventually a footer at the bottom, but I have to get simple working first. If I use a fix number. If I put a number in the typescript code instead of a percentage It shows correctly. If I put 460% in for the height It displays correctly, filling the screen, but if I change the height of the screen and try again it is too big at 460%

Comment: I added 

  redrawOnParentResize: true

In the constructor section for chart so it now reads:

       chart: {
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            type: 'bar',
            redrawOnParentResize: true
          },

In the stackblitz code. 

When I change the dimensions height never changes always about 170px even if I have it full height of my screen or barely and changing width does change the width but height still does not change.

This is the only change I made to the stackblitz code. 

Are you seeing full screen?

Comment: Did you see my question at the end of my last post

Are you seeing full screen height on your stackblitz code?

I am not the height is ~170pixels no matter whatt size the screen is.

Comment: @RodneyEast is this the expected output [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmnzm7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fpolyfills.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: @RodneyEast Please explicitely set the height of the chart, since its will grow based on the container, so you need to set the height on the div with class `chartDiv`

Comment: @RodneyEast you have not shared any stackblitz to me, where you replicated the issue for me to check!

Comment: I like your use of the Aspect ratio, but if someone resizes the screen and it is no longer square the graph now spills out the bottom if the screen. 

With the Aspect ratio, I could have code that calculates a size in pixels and feeds that back into the graph to display at whatever size the new graph space occupies.
This is duplicating something that seems to be built into ApexChart already.

ApexChart does well with width: 100%.  It will fit in the space horizontally beautifully, So I was confused when applying that same methodology to height did not work. 

Thanks